# How can I count field value based on another field?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have `EmailEvent` table. This is STI table which stores opens and clicks (by using `type` attribute). I have right now this code which provides information on how many emails use recipient address (`email_address` field):

```
EmailEvent.where("type = 'OpenEmailEvent' OR type = 'ClickEmailEvent'")
.where(email_id: email_ids).happened_between_dates(start_date, end_date)
.select("email_address, count(distinct email_id) as emails_count")
.group(:email_address).reorder(nil)
```

It generates such code:

```
SELECT email_address, count(distinct email_id) as emails_count 
FROM "email_events" 
WHERE "email_events"."deleted_at" IS NULL 
    AND (type = 'OpenEmailEvent' OR type = 'ClickEmailEvent') 
    AND "email_events"."email_id" IN (85487, 75554, 85489, 77184, 78562, 75587, 82879, 85535, 85534) 
    AND (created_at between '2017-02-28 22:52:01.000000' AND '2017-03-29 05:59:59.000000') 
GROUP BY "email_events"."email_address"
```

I need to provide information on how many opens and clicks there per `email_address`. I can't use `count(id)` because it'll give me both opens and clicks so I need to use `type` attribute somehow but I can't figure out exactly how it should work. Can somebody give me suggestion what should I do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace this

```
count(distinct email_id) as emails_count
```

to  something like in SQLServer using case or IIF

```
sum(case when type = 'OpenEmailEvent' then 1 else 0 end)  [Opens],
sum(case when type = 'ClickEmailEvent' then 1 else 0 end)  [Click],
```

Comment: I don't need to remove it `count(distinct email_id) as emails_count` since I still need that information but your code is exactly what I needed! Thank you!